# How can I reduce the number of nested if statements in this code?

Tags: java, android

The application I'm building can accept two types of updates: Application Update and Parameter Updates. If there is an application update, then parameter updates can be ignored. This is the code that I've written, and it's messy.  How can I clean this up?

```
mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
//experimental();
//check for updates
UpdateMode updateInstallationMode = Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateMode();
if(updateInstallationMode==UpdateMode.MANUAL)
{
    //User will manually install update - no further action needed to be performed by activity.
    //proceed to next screen.
    gotoNextActivity();
}else
{
    boolean shouldConfirm = (updateInstallationMode == UpdateMode.CONFIRM);

    lblStatus.setText(getString(R.string.checking_for_updates));
    Error outUpdateError = new Error();
    Map<String,String> availableUpdates = checkForUpdates(outUpdateError);

    boolean appUpdatesAvailable = availableUpdates.containsKey("application");
    boolean paramUpdatesAvailable = availableUpdates.containsKey("parameters");
    boolean appUpdatesAccepted = Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateType()==UpdateType.BOTH
            || Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateType()==UpdateType.APPLICATION;
    boolean paramUpdatesAccepted = Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateType() == UpdateType.BOTH
            || Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateType() == UpdateType.PARAMETERS;

    if(appUpdatesAccepted && appUpdatesAvailable){
        boolean shouldInstall = shouldConfirm? confirmInstallUpdate(UpdateType.APPLICATION):true;
        if(shouldInstall){
            downloadUpdate(UpdateType.APPLICATION,availableUpdates.get("application"));
        }else{
            gotoNextActivity();
        }

    }else if(paramUpdatesAccepted && paramUpdatesAvailable){
        boolean shouldInstall = shouldConfirm? confirmInstallUpdate(UpdateType.PARAMETERS):true;
        if(shouldInstall){
            downloadUpdate(UpdateType.PARAMETERS,availableUpdates.get("parameters"));
        }else{
            gotoNextActivity();
        }
    }else{
        lblStatus.setText(getString(R.string.app_up_to_date));
        gotoNextActivity();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the code in the question is a method. If not extract it out to a method.

1. ```
   boolean appUpdatesAccepted = Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateType() == UpdateType.BOTH
           || Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateType() == UpdateType.APPLICATION;
   boolean paramUpdatesAccepted = Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateType() == UpdateType.BOTH
           || Parameters.load(mContext).getUpdateType() == UpdateType.PARAMETERS;
   ```

   I'd start with removing some duplication here.

   ```
   UpdateParameters updateParameters = Parameters.load(mContext);

   ...

   final UpdateType updateType = updateParameters.getUpdateType();
   boolean appUpdatesAccepted = updateType == UpdateType.BOTH
           || updateType == UpdateType.APPLICATION;
   boolean paramUpdatesAccepted = updateType == UpdateType.BOTH
           || updateType == UpdateType.PARAMETERS;
   ```

   I'm not familiar with Android, so `UpdateParameters` and `UpdateType` types could be something else.
2. If you reorder the `boolean` variables you can find some more duplication:

   ```
   final boolean appUpdatesAvailable = availableUpdates
       .containsKey("application");
   final boolean appUpdatesAccepted = updateType == UpdateType.BOTH
       || updateType == UpdateType.APPLICATION;

   final boolean paramUpdatesAvailable = availableUpdates
       .containsKey("parameters");
   final boolean paramUpdatesAccepted = updateType == UpdateType.BOTH
       || updateType == UpdateType.PARAMETERS;
   ```

   This could be extracted out to a method:

   ```
   private boolean isUpdateAvailable(
           final Map<String, String> availableUpdates,
           final UpdateParameters updateParameters, 
           final UpdateType updateType, final String updateKey) {
       final UpdateType availableUpdateType = updateParameters
           .getUpdateType();
       final boolean appUpdatesAvailable = availableUpdates
           .containsKey(updateKey);
       final boolean appUpdatesAccepted = 
           availableUpdateType == UpdateType.BOTH 
           || availableUpdateType == updateType;
       return appUpdatesAvailable && appUpdatesAccepted;
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   final boolean tryApplicationUpdate = 
       isUpdateAvailable(availableUpdates, updateParameters, 
           UpdateType.APPLICATION, "application");
   final boolean tryParametersUpdate = 
       isUpdateAvailable(availableUpdates, updateParameters, 
           UpdateType.PARAMETERS, "parameters");
   if (tryApplicationUpdate) {
       ...
   } else if (tryParametersUpdate) {
       ...
   } else {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. It's also possible to extract out the first two `if` blocks to a method, they are very similar to each other:

   ```
   private void downloadUpdateIfConfirmed(
           final boolean shouldConfirm, 
           final Map<String, String> availableUpdates,
           final UpdateType currentUpdateType, final String updateKey) {
       final boolean shouldInstall = shouldConfirm ? 
           confirmInstallUpdate(currentUpdateType) : true;
       if (shouldInstall) {
           downloadUpdate(currentUpdateType, availableUpdates.get(updateKey));
       } else {
           gotoNextActivity();
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   if (tryApplicationUpdate) {
       downloadUpdateIfConfirmed(shouldConfirm, availableUpdates, 
           UpdateType.APPLICATION, "application");
   } else if (tryParametersUpdate) {
       downloadUpdateIfConfirmed(shouldConfirm, availableUpdates, 
           UpdateType.PARAMETERS, "parameters");
   } else {
       ...
   }
   ```
4. I'd move the `shouldConfirm` flag into the method (to reduce its scope, see *Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*); use [guard clauses](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html); create another method which calls `gotoNextActivity()` to remove its duplication:

   ```
   public void update() {
       doUpdate();
       gotoNextActivity();
   }

   private void doUpdate() {
       mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
       final UpdateParameters updateParameters = Parameters.load(mContext);
       final UpdateMode updateInstallationMode = 
           updateParameters.getUpdateMode();
       if (updateInstallationMode == UpdateMode.MANUAL) {
           return;
       }
       lblStatus.setText(getString(RString.checking_for_updates));
       final Error outUpdateError = new Error();
       final Map<String, String> availableUpdates = 
           checkForUpdates(outUpdateError);

       final boolean tryApplicationUpdate = 
           isUpdateAvailable(availableUpdates, updateParameters,
               UpdateType.APPLICATION, "application");
       final boolean tryParametersUpdate = 
           isUpdateAvailable(availableUpdates, updateParameters,
               UpdateType.PARAMETERS, "parameters");
       if (tryApplicationUpdate) {
           downloadUpdateIfConfirmed(updateInstallationMode, 
               availableUpdates, UpdateType.APPLICATION, "application");
           return;
       }
       if (tryParametersUpdate) {
           downloadUpdateIfConfirmed(updateInstallationMode, 
               availableUpdates, UpdateType.PARAMETERS, "parameters");
           return;
       }
       lblStatus.setText(getString(RString.app_up_to_date));
   }

   private void downloadUpdateIfConfirmed(
           final UpdateMode updateInstallationMode,
           final Map<String, String> availableUpdates, 
              final UpdateType updateType, final String updateKey) {
       final boolean shouldConfirm = 
           (updateInstallationMode == UpdateMode.CONFIRM);
       final boolean shouldInstall = shouldConfirm ? 
           confirmInstallUpdate(updateType) : true;
       if (shouldInstall) {
           downloadUpdate(updateType, availableUpdates.get(updateKey));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much! What I loved is that you took it step by step explaining your thought process along the way. That's really helpful - Excellent Answer!